# How to create parent node and append child node to its and then appent parrent noded to nativeElement in angular/ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

**Hi I want to create a parent node and append child node  to it and then append parent node to nativeElement in ionic/Angular 2**

```
ionView=this.renderer.createElement('div');
sideMenu =this.renderer.createElement('p');
ioninsideview=this.renderer.createElement('h1');
this.renderer.appendChild(ionView, sideMenu);
this.renderer.appendChild(ionView, ioninsideview);
this.renderer.appendChild(this.abcd.nativeElement, ionView);
```

it throws error failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: `renderer` is not a `nativeElement`.

Comment: Then how it can acheive

Comment: Use document.getElementById() or the @ViewChild decorator from Angular. More info can be found at: https://alligator.io/angular/viewchild-access-component/